# Initiated dictionary value in __init__ not being called when using self even though it's initiated

Tags: python, json, file, oop, python-requests

An imported file "discordPing" with the class discordPing is being called at discordPing.getTokenID("filename.txt") - All scripts are in the same file.
Since I'm very new to using object-oriented, but when I ran the original discord ping code without having any classes involved it worked.

Main.py

```
from discordPing import discordPing
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #setup()
    discordPing.getTokenID("token.txt")
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
            message = discordPing.getMessage("Unlock")
            if (message == "Unlock"):
                discordPing.sendMessage("Unlock Sequence Innitiated")
                print("Unlocked")       
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Program Ended")
        #destroy()
```

discordPing.py

```
#Discord Ping System
import requests
import json

class discordPing():
    def __init__(self, payload, channelLink, header):
        self.payload = {"content":"Hello World"}
        self.channelLink = "https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/1088876738144112735/messages"
        self.header = {"authorization": "Empty"}
    
    @classmethod   
    def getTokenID(self, fileLocation):
        """

        Parameters
        ----------
        fileLocation : String - File Location
            DESCRIPTION. Loads token into header - Necessary to use script.

        Returns
        -------
        None.

        """
        f = open(fileLocation)
        tk = f.read()
        self.header["authorization"] = tk
    
    @classmethod   
    def sendMessage(self ,messageContent):
        """

        Parameters
        ----------
        messageContent : String - Content of Message
            DESCRIPTION: Whatever text needs to be sent.

        Returns
        -------
        None.

        """
        pload = self.payload["content"] = messageContent
        requests.post(self.channelLink, data=pload,headers=self.header)
    @classmethod   
    def getMessage(self, message):
        """

        Parameters
        ----------
        message : String 
            DESCRIPTION: Replaces string with last sent message

        Returns
        -------
        message : String
            DESCRIPTION.Returns replaced string with last sent message

        """
        r = requests.get(self.channelLink, headers=self.header)
        js = json.loads(r.text)
        for value in js:
            message = value['content']
            break
        return message
```

Original Working Reference Code

```
import requests
import json
import time
def getTokenID():
    f = open("token.txt")
    return(f.read())

def sendMessage(payload,header,channelLink,messageContent):
    payload["content"] = messageContent
    requests.post(channelLink, data=payload,headers=header)

def getMessage(channelLink,header):
    r = requests.get(channelLink, headers=header)
    js = json.loads(r.text)
    for value in js:
        messages.append(value['content'])
        break

messages = []
token = getTokenID()
channelLink = "https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/1088876738144112735/messages"
#Change Data of content to change message 
payload = {"content":"Hello World"}
header={"authorization":token}

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        getMessage(channelLink, header)
        if (messages[0] == "Unlock"):
            print("Unlocking")
            sendMessage(payload,header,channelLink, "Unlock Sequence Complete")
        print(messages)
        messages = []
```

What the code is supposed to do is to take the discord token stored in the text file, and read a sent message, if the latest message is "Unlock", it sends a message that unlock sequence has been complete.

The error is occurring when trying to store the inputed token into self.header inside '**init**'.

The Error recieved

```
runfile('C:/Users/115al/Desktop/Testing/Token ID/main.py', wdir='C:/Users/115al/Desktop/Testing/Token ID')
Reloaded modules: discordPing
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\115al\Desktop\Testing\Token ID\main.py", line 28, in <module>
    discordPing.getTokenID("token.txt")

  File "C:\Users\115al\Desktop\Testing\Token ID\discordPing.py", line 27, in getTokenID
    self.header["authorization"] = tk

AttributeError: type object 'discordPing' has no attribute 'header'
```

Comment: discordPing is class method and thus, it does not have access to instance variables ..  https://pynative.com/python-instance-variables/